# When running Nightwatch.js test how can I get the name of browser currently running the tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, testing, nightwatch.js

**Situation**: We are running tests in several browsers using Nightwatch
(*via Saucelabs; everything runs fine on Saucelabs*).

**Desired**: we want to know ***which browser*** the test is *currently* running in so we can save screenshots including the browser name.

Is it possible to determine which browser is running the tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its quite simple, when running a Nightwatch test, the `browser` (*or `client`*) parameter is passed in, eg:

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test GitHub': function (browser) {
    console.log(browser.options); // this will output the browser details
    browser
      .url('http://www.github.com/dwyl')   // visit the url
      .waitForElementVisible('body'); // wait for the body to be rendered
      .assert.containsText('body', 'do what you love') // assert contains
      .saveScreenshot('dwyl_github.png')
      .end();
  }
};
```

The `browser` Object contains an `options` Object with the following form:

```
{ screenshots: true,
  screenshotsPath: './node_modules/nightwatch/screenshots/1.0.20/',
  skip_testcases_on_fail: true,
  log_screenshot_data: true,
  username: 'thisguy',
  accessKey: 'notimportant',
  desiredCapabilities: 
   { browserName: 'internet explorer',
     javascriptEnabled: true,
     acceptSslCerts: true,
     platform: 'Windows 10',
     version: '11.0',
     name: 'Github' } }
```

So we wrote a little helper function to format the name of the browser into a string we could include in the screenshot file name:

```
function userAgent(browser) { // see: https://git.io/vobdn
  var a = browser.options.desiredCapabilities;
  return (a.platform + '~' + a.browserName + '~' + a.version).replace(/ /g, '');
}
```

Which is then used as:

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test GitHub': function (browser) {
    console.log(browser.options); // this will output the browser details
    browser
      .url('http://www.github.com/dwyl')   // visit the url
      .waitForElementVisible('body'); // wait for the body to be rendered
      .assert.containsText('body', 'do what you love') // assert contains
      .saveScreenshot(userAgent(browser) + '_dwyl_github.png')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Example filename: `Windows10~internetexplorer~11.0~dwyl_github.png`

The reason for using `~` ("tilde") as the word separator was so we can later `split` on this character in our screenshot viewer. 
See: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch for more detail.